# Whitelisting applications in Windows7

Tags: operating-systems, windows, hardening, configuration

Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 come with a security tool called [Applocker](http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2009/05/21/windows-7-app-locker.aspx). This allows admins to restrict applications to a specific white list which can be as granular as the individual application versions.

Apart from considerations of how practical this is to run, how much real world security would running a fairly tight config provide to an 'average' home system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whitelisting applications is a defense-in-depth measure.  While it won't prevent a truly determined person from doing something nefarious, it will stop most people -- especially if users are running as non-admin.

Practicality is relative to your environment.  If it's as you say, a home system, then the liklihood is that you don't have group policy in place.  You would have to manage the configuration on each system manually.

Comment: default-deny for applications is *very* good idea and provides much higher security than having just antivirus and antimalware